# Wordpress Internal Server Error (real soccer theme)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I'm building a wordpress but something is wrong. When I go to my website it's telling me:

> > Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request. Please contact the server
>   administrator to inform of the time the error occurred and of anything
>   you might have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.

But strangely enough I can visit my admin panel with wp-admin. I can't see a .htacces file in my root, but normally when you go to permalinks and press save that file is made automatically but can't see it? In filezilla I've the right settings so there are now hidden files.

Also I've increase the memory and disabled all plugins. When I select another theme in wordpress it works!

What could be wrong? Obviously there is something wrong with the .htacces file.

Comment: try adding the default [.htaccess file](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess) to your root directory.

Comment: @cylua thanks for your reply. But that doesn't work.

Comment: oh, when you select another theme in Wordpress it works. i miss read this part. Most likely due to an error in your existing theme. is there any error_log around you can download and take a look? it should tell you what goes wrong with your current theme!

Comment: Are you able to access the server logs? If so; check them.